# How to restore a directory with Bareos/Bacula while excluding deleted files?

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, bacula, bareos

I would like to restore a directory so that it is identical to the original directory. Files that have been deleted in the original directory should not be restored.

Consider a configuration file directory: The original version of this directory and contents will be in the first full backup. Over time some of the files will be deleted intentionally. But they are not marked as deleted in the incremental backups.

If I restore this directory from the backup and the deleted files show up again, I will end up with a different configuration, so the restored system is not useable.

When evaluating Bareos using the web-ui, I could not figure out how to set up the restore process so that files deleted in the past are not restored. Please advise how to accomplish this.

If this can't be done with Bareos/Bacula, can you recommend a different backup that fulfills this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bareos check out    Accurate =   in the documention. Even I did not use it so far it should fulfill you needs.

http://doc.bareos.org/master/html/bareos-manual-main-reference.html#directiveDirJobAccurate